# Include query results in application insights alert to webhook

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams, azure-application-insights

I try to setup an application insights alert to a webhook (MS Teams to be precise). I already successfully managed to create the alert and the data is already sent to the webhook and displayed in Teams.

This is a log-alert.

All I am now missing is the query-RESULT of that log-alert.
The documentation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log-webhook#log-alert-with-a-custom-json-payload] simply states that I need to add a simple configuration-parameter into the payload:

`"IncludeSearchResults":true`

Which I did. But still no Json-Attachment (or anything else) to be seen containing the query result.
My complete payload (which works fine apart from the result-part) looks like this:

```
{   
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "IncludeSearchResults":true,
    "themeColor": "CC4216",
    "title": "#alertrulename",
    "text": "#alertrulename returned #searchresultcount records which exceeds the threshold of #thresholdvalue .",
    "summary": "Query: #searchquery",

    "potentialAction": [{
        "@type": "OpenUri",
        "name": "See details in AppInsights",
        "targets": [{
            "os": "default",
            "uri": "#linktosearchresults"
        }]
    }],
    "sections": [{
        "facts": [{
            "name": "Severity:",
            "value": "#severity"
        },
        {
            "name": "Query:",
            "value": "#searchquery"
        },
        {
            "name": "ResultCount:",
            "value": "#searchresultcount"
        },
        {
            "name": "Search Interval StartTime:",
            "value": "#searchintervalstarttimeutc"
        },
        {
            "name": "Search Interval End time:",
            "value": "#searchintervalendtimeutc"
        },
        {
            "name": "AppInsights Application ID:",
            "value": "#applicationid"
        }]
    }]
}
```

What I want to achieve is that the "top 10 results" that are automatically added to any email-notification also be shown in Teams:
[image]

Comment: Card you shared is [O365 Connector card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference). `IncludeSearchResults` property is not part of the schema. Could you please add more detials on what are you expecting to show up in Microsoft Teams?

Comment: I extended my question

Answer (score 0):

O365 connector card schema does not contain IncludeSearchResults property.
You will need to fetch the result and then bind the data to card.
Are you able to fetch the results?

Comment: Do you have any example of how to achieve this from the alert rule itself?